# What's the difference between the 'Burning', 'Poisoned', and 'Disoriented' status debuffs?

Tags: xcom-2

What's the difference between the 'Burning', 'Poisoned', and 'Disoriented' status debuffs? I know for sure that Burning and Poisoned deal a damage over time effect to affected teammates and enemies, but is that all? What does Disoriented do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the XCOM Mod Buddy, there are several statuses that prevent abilities from being used: Disoriented, Burning (Acid is burning too), Carrying Units, Bound, Confused, and Stunned.

Here's the other thing - every single action is an ability, including firing -- but since the game wants you to be able to fire while burning, they added in exceptions for particular abilities and particular statuses. So rather than list every ability that's blocked, I'm going to list every ability that *isn't* blocked (it's a much smaller list!).

### Burning

- Is cleared upon entering water
- Damage Over Time (varies, depending on source)
- Prevents use of all non-passive Abilities except: Interact, Hunker Down, Medkit *Heal* Use, EVACing, Melee Attacks, Gremlin *Heal* commands, and Shooting.

### Disoriented

- -20 Aim
- -30 Will
- -6 Mobility (Tiles)
- Prevents use of all non-passive Abilities except: Overwatch, Reload, Looting, Hunker Down, EVACing, Suppression, Rupture(!?), Lightning Hands, and Shooting.

### Poisoned

- -30 Aim
- -4 Mobility (Tiles)
- Damage Over Time (can vary, depending on source)
- Spreads to Adjacent Units (Yes, even Vipers'. I realize this makes no sense)

Poisoned and Disorient aim and movement penalties are defined by the defaults, which I *believe* correspond to .ini files that I haven't found yet, so if someone knows the default values, I'll happily add those in.

Comment: Thanks, most of my answer was purely anecdotal but thanks for the super in-depth answer :)

Comment: The .ini values you're looking for are in XComGameCore.ini under XComGame.X2StatusEffects. Lots of good info there, such as the fact that being disoriented gives you -30 will.

Comment: Even though this was not part of the question, you could also add "Acid Burn" and "Crysalid Poision" to the list for sake of completeness.

Comment: @Philipp in the first line i mention that acid burn is another form of burning. I'm not sure chyrssalid poison behaves differently from regular poison.