# Which Enemy abilities are prevented by Burn/Poison/Disorient?

Tags: xcom-2

As per title: there is a very nice Q&A detailing which of our soldier's skills are unusable when under negative status effects, but what about enemies' abilities?

Comment: I don't have nearly a complete list for this, but I do know that disorienting a Sectoid will break mind control on XCOM soldiers AND immediately kill any psi-zombie he may have raised.  Makes flashbang grenades very useful vs Sectoids in the early game.

Comment: Yes, Flashbangs are also really useful vs Codexes, since they definitely block the split, and maybe also the "bubble" and teleport.

Comment: Not a duplicate per se, but [answered here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254775/whats-the-difference-between-the-burning-poisoned-and-disoriented-statu/254967#254967)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Sorry, it doesn't look like it is answered there, all the abilities in the list are Unit abilities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some information in the XCOM-2 Wiki.

[disoriented:](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Disoriented)

> It will also cancel overwatch, suppression, mind control, and reanimated corpses if used on the creator of the zombie. [...]
>
> - Mutons cannot counter-attack in melee
> - Psionic aliens cannot use any Psi
> - Codex can neither teleport nor clone itself

[burning](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Burning)

> - Prevents reloading
> - Prevents melee attacks from Rangers, Berserkers, Stun Lancers & Chryssalids (possibly more)
> - Archons may still melee, even while burning.
> - Stun Lancers appear to panic, causing them to move randomly and fire their rifle.
> - Prevents hacking
> - Prevents Overwatch
> - Prevents most cooldown-affected abilities, such as Suppression from the Grenadier

Poisoning just damages, & decreases mobility and aim.